# How to disable Keep-Alive per Directory

Tags: apache, keep-alive

Is it possible to disable Keep-Alive on a directory basis?

For example, I have an API that runs on something like domain.com/api/

It'd be nice if KeepAlive was not used on any requests in the /api/ directory.

---

**Update/Solution:**

> SetEnvIf Request_URI /api/ nokeepalive

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a recent feature of Apache HTTPD, but it works.

To disable (turn off) Keep-Alive for a specific directory, use:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /myDir/ nokeepalive
```

Add this to your `httpd.conf` **or** `.htaccess` file!

Source: [Environment Variables in Apache - Special Purpose Environment Variables - nokeepalive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#nokeepalive).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways I found:
1. As described by acdcjunior you can do it with SetEnvIf inside your Virtual host or main configuration

`SetEnvIf Request_URI /myDir/ nokeepalive`

2. You can just set the Connection header to close

`Header set Connection "close"`

I prefer the second option due to the fact that this will allow the entire configuration to be under the

Answer (score 0):

No! the context for the keep-alive directive is: server config, virtual host